# Suggest a minimalist HTTP proxy with certain features

Tags: linux, proxy, http

Please suggest me a minimalist HTTP proxy for Linux which has the following features:

- a single executable file - it can be an executable compiled from C/C++ or a Python/Perl script
- accepts the IP:port to listen from command line at startup
- doesn't do any caching, only in RAM
- can block URLs by regexp
- uses a simple text file as backend for URLs that need to be blocked - one pattern per line
- has a way to accept more URLs to block at runtime and is able to save them as well
- has a verbose mode that dumps blocked urls to stdout (for debugging purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at all of the ones mentioned on this [website](http://proxies.xhaus.com/)? It lists some in java and python.

Comment: The site has some broken links, some references to ancient software. But I've found a couple of candidates that I hopefully will be able to tweak for my needs. Thank you.